# An xy-problem in LaTex - How to define a command in LaTex that prints particular text based on number input?

Tags: macros

The current code, as shown below, prints out figure captions with wind directions in degrees. I am looking for a way to keep the for loop and change the wind directions in the captions to texts, such as N, S, E, W, SW, SE, etc.

```
\foreach \wind in {135,157,180,202,225,236,247,258} {%

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Wind_report_of\wind_direction.png}
        \caption{Wind Direction: \wind°}\label{Design\wind}
    \end{figure}
}
```

Comment: Ar you looking for something like `\ifnum\wind>180 print something \else print something else \fi`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I did consider the '''\ifnum''' function. However, there are 12 words for the wind directions, which means there will be a stack of '''\ifnum''' and '''fi'''. I am very new to LaTex, and wonder if there is any simpler way of doing so (perhaps a macro that exists).

Comment: Finally, the if-statement handled the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Nice to hear your problem is solved! It would be great if you could share your knowledge with future users with the same problem by writing an answer below.

Comment: Asking for help with doing something without precisely describing what shall be done is not good practice. Can you precisely describe the mapping of degrees to text so that one knows what one shall implement in TeX? What text shall be delivered under what conditions? Do you only need to evaluate equality of degree-specifications? Do you need to evaluate in what range of values a degree-specification is?

Answer (score 3):

You can give both in the `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \wind/\windtext in {135/E,157/SE,180/S,202/SW,225/W,236/WN,247/WNN,258/N} {%
\wind/\windtext \quad}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{wind135}{A}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{wind157}{N}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{wind180}{S}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{wind202}{NW}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{wind225}{B}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{wind236}{E}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{wind247}{SW}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{wind258}{W}

\foreach \wind in {135,157,180,202,225,236,247,258} {%

\wind\ is \UseName{wind\wind}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Never mind. I think I get it. Thanks for this answer. It's really helpful. What else could `c` be? Is there something to get it to expand something after the cs name?